# error al activar un script con formsubmit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, form-submit

El siguiente es el email que recibí ante la falla al completar el formulario por primera vez.

Tu secuencia de comandos, Formulario de consultas y trámites, no se ha ejecutado correctamente. A continuación incluimos un resumen de los errores. Para configurar los activadores de la secuencia de comandos o cambiar la configuración para recibir futuras notificaciones de errores, haz clic aquí.

El documento Formulario de consultas y trámites utiliza la secuencia de comandos.

Estoy obteniendo este error:

> Inicio:   18/10/17 12:34   Función:   showQuestionNumber   Mensaje de
>   error:    No se puede usar FormApp.getUi() desde este contexto. (línea 5,
>   archivo "Código") Activación: formSubmit   Fin: 18/10/17 12:34
>   Atentamente,
>
> Google Apps Script

El código del script es muy sencillo:

```
function showQuestionNumber() {

      var questionnumber=5

      FormApp.getUi().alert('Su consulta tramitará con el número:    '+ questionnumber)
    }
```

Les agradezco que me ayuden a solucionar este inconveniente.
Saludos
Salvador

Comment: Hola Salvador, bienvenido al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! para que obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Comment: Si hay algo que no se entiende@Jorgesys, lo aclaro.

Comment: Salvador, de hecho te agradezco hayas realizado el [tour] y revisado el documento, lo que menciona te ayudará a crear una buena pregunta y por ende tener mejores respuestas! @Salvador

Answer (score 0):

Como lo indica el mensaje de error `FormApp.getUI()` sólo se puede usar cuando se ejecuta el script en el contexto del editor de formularios de Google, no es posible llamarlo usando el activador "al enviar formulario" así como tampoco es posible ejecutar scripts en la vista para responder formularios.